# Codenameone associating mimetype(PNG) to my App

Tags: android, codenameone, mime-types, intentfilter

i have a problem with associating a mime/file type (PNG) to my App
i followed this guide:
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/associating-your-app-with-file-extension-mime-types-iphone-android-windows.html
i set these build hints (for Android)

```
android.activity.launchMode=singleTask
```

and android.xintent_filter like this (i tried image/png and image/* as mimetype)-->

```
<intent-filter>       <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />     <data android:mimeType="image/*" />   </intent-filter>   <intent-filter >       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />       <data android:mimeType="image/*" />  </intent-filter>  <intent-filter >       <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />       <data android:mimeType="image/*" />  </intent-filter>
```

[here my Build Hints as a ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ScGD.jpg)

my App shows up in the "open with" or "share" Dialog, but the `Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppArg", null)` returns nothing (null) at start.
I created a Dialog after form.show() like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wned.jpg) to check...

if i use the Simulator with the argument -->
"file://home/pic.png"
everything works fine..

i don't know if it matters... i have a OnePlus 8 Pro with Android 11 that i use for testing

here a few Screenshots from the "[open with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dneKO.jpg)" and "[share](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiFOg.jpg)" Dialog

```
     public void start() 
    {
        String arg = Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppArg", null);
        if(arg != null)
        {
            System.out.println("opend with arg");
            
            MainForm m = new MainForm();
            Display.getInstance().createThread(new Runnable() 
            {
//              @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    System.out.println(arg);
                    m.do_something(arg);
                    
                    
                }}, "open from Outside Thread").start();
            
            current = m.create(false);
            current.revalidate();  
            
        }else 
        {
            if(current == null)
            {
                current = new MainForm().create(true);
                Display.getInstance().scheduleBackgroundTask(new Runnable() 
                {
                        @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        if(!Display.getInstance().isSimulator()) 
                        {
                            Storage.getInstance().clearStorage();
                            Storage.getInstance().clearCache();
                        }
                    }
                    
                });
                current.revalidate(); 
            }
        }
        
        current.show();
        if(arg != null)
        {
            Dialog.show("Test", arg + " - " + arg.length(), "OK", "Cancel"); 
        }else 
        {
            Dialog.show("Test", "AppArg = null ", "OK", "Cancel");
        }
//      disp.setProperty("AppArg", null);
        
    }
```

here my second attempt, with only the necessary code to start the app.

```
      public void start() 
    {
        arg = Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppArg", null);
        
        if(arg != null) 
        {
            Storage.getInstance().writeObject("Arg", arg);
            Log.p(arg);
        }
//          if(arg != null) 
//          {
//     
            
            
//              MainForm m = new MainForm();
//              Display.getInstance().createThread(new Runnable() 
//              {
////                @Override
//              public void run() 
//              {
//                  System.out.println(arg);
//                  m.do_something(arg);
//                  
//                  
//              }}, "open from Outside Thread").start();
//              
//              current = m.create(false);
//              current.revalidate();  
            
//          }else 
//          {
            if(current == null)
            {
                current = new MainForm().create(true);
//                  Display.getInstance().scheduleBackgroundTask(new Runnable() 
//                  {
//                      @Override
//                      public void run() 
//                      {
//                          if(!Display.getInstance().isSimulator()) 
//                          {
//                              Storage.getInstance().clearStorage();
//                              Storage.getInstance().clearCache();
//                          }
//                      }
//                      
//                  });
                current.revalidate(); 
            }
//          }
        
        current.show();
        if(arg != null)
        {
            
            Dialog.show("Test", arg + " - " + arg.length(), "OK", "Cancel"); 
        }else 
        {
            Dialog.show("Test","" + Storage.getInstance().readObject("Arg") + Log.getLogContent(), "OK", "Cancel");
        }
//      disp.setProperty("AppArg", null);
        
    }
```

---

```
    06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/data/user/0/de.marcus.myapp/files/IMG_20210601_201624_pic.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.createFileOuputStream(AndroidImplementation.java:6530)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.getAppArg(AndroidImplementation.java:2731)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at com.codename1.ui.Display.getProperty(Display.java:3361)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at de.marcus.myapp.MyApplication.start(Unknown Source:8)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at de.marcus.myapp.MyApplicationStub.run(MyApplicationStub.java:163)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at de.marcus.myapp.MyApplicationStub$1.run(MyApplicationStub.java:107)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1365)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1307)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1480)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1519)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation$3.run(AndroidImplementation.java:1147)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1365)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1307)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1189)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
06-04 13:50:49.618  8269 16651 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
06-04 13:50:49.619  8269 16651 W System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-04 13:50:49.619  8269 16651 W System.err:    at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
06-04 13:50:49.619  8269 16651 W System.err:    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
06-04 13:50:49.619  8269 16651 W System.err:    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
06-04 13:50:49.619  8269 16651 W System.err:    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
06-04 13:50:49.619  8269 16651 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7871)
06-04 13:50:49.619  8269 16651 W System.err:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
06-04 13:50:49.619  8269 16651 W System.err:    ... 19 more
```

Thanks for every help

Marcus

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to Android launch mode.
Try add the build hint:

```
android.activity.launchMode=singleTask
```

Comment: Hi Chen, Unfortunately, I've already tried that

Comment: is this consistent? you never see a value in the AppArg?

Comment: Yes, on my Phone i never See a value, i Always get null.

Comment: can you try on a different android? I wonder if that's a device issue

Comment: Do you see the intent pick window without your app or do you see nothing?

Comment: @Chen I tested it with my tablet(Lenovo Yoga Tab 3 Plus with LineageOs 18.1 (Android 11) ), but unfortunately it didn't work there either

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I added a few pictures,of what i see to the post, the App shows up one the "share" and "open with" Dialog and if i klick on it my App opens... Thanks for your help

Comment: So the app is associated, how do you read the app arg value? Can you include the code of your start method?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Hi, i added my start method to the post (P.s the do_something method is empty...)

Comment: Try removing the `scheduleBackgroundTask`; Clearing the storage can have adverse affects so it might have caused this. Also it's possible the activity was invoked twice once one with arg and one without and you wouldn't see it. Try using Log instead of System.out and save the non-null arg into a static variable that you can check to reshow the UI.

Comment: What version of Android are you using?  It is possible that some newer versions are causing problems with these settings.  Try to look at the device log when to see if any exceptions are reported at the time when you try to get the app arg.  Then post the exception in your question.

Comment: @stevehannah Hi, my phone has Android 11. How can i log that(sorry, i am pretty new in phone/codenameone development)?, because the Mehtod Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppArg", null) doesn't throw any Exception?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Hi, i removed the scheduleBackgroundTask... changed the arg variable to an static string and i immediately write the value of it (if not null) to storage if the activity is invoked twice ... (see my second code part at the top) Thanks for your help

Comment: Google Android kogcat to see the general logs. If you have an older Android somewhere it would be interesting to know if it works there.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Hi, i hope the Log i added is usefull and the right location..., i'll try to get an older Android to give you feedback.

Comment: I think I see a potential problem. I need to push an update today anyway so try again in a couple of hours. Please send a new build then and see if you get the same exception. Please check specifically the file name. I thing the `file:` prefix is the problem here.